# ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = $x

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, auto-increment, alter-table

i would to execute this query but it doesn't work and i don't know why :

```
$query = mysqli_query($connexionUser, "ALTER TABLE creatik AUTO_INCREMENT = '$i'");
```

i check my vars and there are okay.
Auto increment is set on a id column who is primary key if it can help to understand what's wrong.

Thanks to take a look :)

Comment: Errors?  Results? Value of $i?

Comment: Is that the right syntax for ALTER TABLE? Don't you need to specify a column to amend?

Comment: creatik is your table name or column name?

Comment: @andrewsi : It's the same that official doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: now What you want to do with alter command

Comment: Try without the `'` quotes - you're setting an integer, not a string. Plus, make sure you're not setting the auto_increment value to something that already exists in your table. You can seriously munge things up if you try to reuse a value that exists.

Comment: change value of auto_increment with $i.
$connexionUser and $i are fine, i check it many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` expects an integer. It's possible that the quotes are throwing it off, try removing them.

Comment: Yes it was this reason, it's works now !
Marc B was the first on the good way, but thanks everybody for help :)

Comment: You will need to ensure that `$i` >= `1`. (For example, there will be **no change** if you try to set it to `0`.)